# Publish Binaries in TFS 2017 MS BUILD

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

These are my MS build arguments

`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\CC`

What should I use to Publish only binaries using Publish artifacts. I am getting code files only.

Comment: What does your publish artifacts task parameters look like?

Comment: What do you mean with _binaries_? Your MSBuild arguments create a ZIP file plus a a few batch/xml files to be consumed using MSDeploy.

Comment: I see the Zip file and when i extract then folder structure is different always. Can i get those without zip file and i an particular folder structure so next step of copying gets easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to output the files without zip, then you can try below ways:

1. Specify the argument `OutputPath` only (without specify the package
   related arguments):

   e.g:

   `/p:OutputPath="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\cc"`

   You can also output the target files to a shared path (UNC path):

   e.g:

   `/p:OutputPath="\\myshare\DirA\0313"`
2. Then use **Copy and Publish build Artifacts** task to publish the
   files. Alternatively you can add a **Copy Files** task to copy the
   files from `OutputPath` to a **Temp folder**, then use **Publish
   build Artifacts** task to publish the files from **Temp folder**.

Reference the first screenshot.

---

Another workaround is using the publish profile:

1. Create a **Folder publish profile**, you can chose a shared folder
   to publish. (Refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio) to create the publish profile)
2. Add below MSBuild arguments in VS build or MSbuild task:

   ```
    /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=YourPublishProfile
   ```
3. Check the published artifacts.

Reference the second screenshot:

[image: First Screenshot]

[image: Second Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried first one and it worked for me.